# Add Link around every picture

Tags: php, jquery, hyperlink, image

i've got the following problem. I've been moving a large amount of content by hand and while inserting images, i put the lightbox class on the  tag - unfortunately for the images to properly work, they would need an anchor around them specifying the url to the full image size - for example

```
<a href="images/myimage.jpg" class="lightbox"><img src="images/myimage.jpg"></a>
```

All I've got now is :

```
<img src="images/myimage.jpg" class="lightbox">
```

Is it possible to automatically set an anchar around every image found inside a specific `<div>` element and also properly close it? I would need something like

foreach image in `<div>` prepend `<a href="this.image.src">` and append `</a>`

Any solution in PHP or jQuery would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: With HTML5 it isn't necessary, but you should self close your image tag `<img src="images/myimage.jpg" class="lightbox" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.wrap()` method:

```
$('div img').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<a href="'+this.src+'" class="lightbox"></a>');
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/bztvw/

Comment: missed the class nice one though.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery use `.wrap()`:

```
 $.each($('img'), function(){
    $(this).wrap('<a href="'+$(this).attr('src')+'" class="lightbox"></a>')
 });
```

It would be better if you specify the container div of these images then only those images will be wrapped. Something like this:

```
$.each($('#lighboximgwrapper img'), function(){
    $(this).wrap('<a href="'+$(this).attr('src')+'" class="lightbox"></a>')
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RegExp

Pattern:

```
<img(.*)src="([\w\/\.]+)"(.*)>
```

Replace with:

```
<a href="$2" rel="fancybox"><img src="$2" alt="" /></a>
```

preg_replace PHP Function

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would fix the code generating the source.  Just use the regex find/replace in your IDE and fix the source.  Don't rely on some javascript or PHP hack to "fix" this mistake.